# Problema com JS/Jquery/Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Eu tenho um botão que quando clicado ele executa uma função:

```
function searchTradeItems() {
    var uid = $("#useruniqid").val();
    var iusername = $("#username").html();
    var userid = $("#balmung-id").val();
    var itemType = $("#trade-type option:selected").val();
    var valueType = $("#trade-gold-type option:selected").val();
    if (valueType == 5) {
        $("#alert-box").show();
        $("#mensagem-alert").html("Insira o valor da qualidade entre 0 e 100");
        $("#alert-ok").click(function() {
            var iquality = $("#alert-value").val();
            $("#alert-box").fadeOut(200);
            $.ajax({
                url: "systems/action-trade.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    uid: uid,
                    iusername: iusername,
                    itemType: itemType,
                    valueType: valueType,
                    userid: userid,
                    iname: iname,
                    iquality: iquality
                },
                beforeSend: function() {},
                success: function(result) {
                    $("#user-painel-2").html(result);
                    $("#alert-value").val("");
                }
            });
        });
        $("#alert-cancel").click(function() {
            $("#alert-box").fadeOut(200);
        });
    };
    //----------------------------------------
}
```

Até ai ok, ele pega os dados digitados e envia com ajax, funciona, retorna o resultado que eu quero perfeitamente. Mas o problema que se eu repetir essa ação ele vai somando as consultas. No primeiro click ele envia uma solicitação ajax, se eu clicar novamente ele envia duas solicitações ajax, se eu clicar novamente ele envia 3, e assim por diante... o que estaria causando isso?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Ele fez 6 consultas de uma vez só. Como estava funcionando eu só fui reparar nisso depois de um tempo.

Se for algum erro bobo peço perdão, ainda sou iniciante.

Comment: Primeiro, idente seu código, fica mais fácil pra ler. Segundo, a função _searchTradeItems_ você chama apenas uma vez? Terceiro, quando você diz "No primeiro click...", que evento ele dispara? Ou melhor, em que botão está clicando?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare essa função fora da função `searchTradeItems()`.

```
$("#alert-ok").click(function() {
    var iquality = $("#alert-value").val();
    $("#alert-box").fadeOut(200);
    $.ajax({
        url: "systems/action-trade.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            uid: uid,
            iusername: iusername,
            itemType: itemType,
            valueType: valueType,
            userid: userid,
            iname: iname,
            iquality: iquality
        },
        beforeSend: function() {},
        success: function(result) {
            $("#user-painel-2").html(result);
            $("#alert-value").val("");
        }
    });
}); 

function searchTradeItems() {
    var uid = $("#useruniqid").val();
    var iusername = $("#username").html();
    var userid = $("#balmung-id").val();
    var itemType = $("#trade-type option:selected").val();
    var valueType = $("#trade-gold-type option:selected").val();
    if (valueType == 5) {
        $("#alert-box").show();
        $("#mensagem-alert").html("Insira o valor da qualidade entre 0 e 100");
        $("#alert-cancel").click(function() {
            $("#alert-box").fadeOut(200);
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: Atualizei meu POSTE

Comment: Boa Gumball, agora foi... Então era por eu ter declarado dentro do searchTradeItems? De qualquer forma valeu pela ajuda!

Comment: @JacksonAntunes Não! É porquê a cada clique que você dava ele guardava o evento e replicava no próximo clique. Porquê toda vez que você abria o modal declarava a função. Então, era como se tivesse várias funções da mesma. Se resolveu, marque como resolvido, por favor.